# SoundCloud Desktop Sharing Kit Broken?

Tags: desktop-application, soundcloud

I'm using the SoundCloud Desktop Sharing Kit in a Renoise plugin. It let's Renoise user upload directly to SoundCloud. AKA:

- https://github.com/soundcloud/soundcloud-win-sharing
- https://github.com/soundcloud/soundcloud-mac-sharing

The instructions on those pages say:

*If you plan to use the Windows version the redirect URI has to be set to "http://connect.soundcloud.com/desktop", so best use this one in general.*

This has been working fine up until recently. Now that URL gives a 404, breaking the tool.

Help?

Comment: Hi There, a broken deploy killed the http://connect.soundcloud.com/desktop resource. We've fixed the problem. Could you please try again?

Comment: Seems fixed now. Thanks Paul Osman.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The feature was temporary broken. It's fixed now. See Paul's comment above. (Jan 18th).